# How can I initialize a Realm configuration in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

In Kotlin I put the following in my MainApplication.kt class.

```
Realm.init(this);
val realmConfig: RealmConfiguration = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
    .name("app.realm")
    .schemaVersion(0)
    .build()
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig)
```

Afterwards, I can get an instance of the default Realm with the following code:

```
val realm: Realm? = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
```

What would be the equivalent code in Swift? And where should I put it so that the instance is accessible from anywhere within my app? Should I put it in AppDelegate.swift?

All I know is that I should use the following code when reading and writing to my Realm, but what do I need to write to configure the database in the first place? And how can I later fetch that default configuration?

```
let realm = try? Realm()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize a Realm in Swift, you aren't creating a new database per-se, you're creating a container that can hold one or more realms, or reference the default one created by try! Realm(). So, if you want to access the same Realm across your app, it's as simple as re-initializing it in each class (as weird as that sounds) or, if you are configuring your realm, passing it the same configuration properties on each initialization.

I don't know Kotlin, but from what I can tell you are trying to pass configuration details to a new Realm instance. To do that in swift, create your configuration object first, then use it to initialize the Realm itself (put it into the App Delegate in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, then make sure to use the same configuration in your other classes):

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(
fileURL: <URL?>, //i think this is the "name" property equivalent
schemaVersion: <UInt64>,
)
```

Then, when you initialize the Realm instance:

```
let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
```